# Run Apache Zeppelin as different User

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

How can I run a Zeppelin interpreter as a different user than the user who started the process?

I want to run Zeppelin as "root" and then launch a spark application as "admin" user

Answer (score 0):

You can keep running Zeppelin as you're currently doing, but start the Spark process separately as that admin user.

The Spark interpreter can be pointed to an external master. Open the Zeppelin interpreter config and change the value of the spark master config key, pointing it to the instance started by the admin user.

In other words, you have one process for spark:

```
# First run spark as admin:
$ /path/to/spark/sbin/start-all.sh

# Then run zeppelin as root:
# /path/to/zeppelin/bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh start
```

According to the [Zeppelin documentation for the Spark interpreter](http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/interpreter/spark.html), you can point Zeppelin to a separate master by changing the value of the `master` configuration.
The default value for this config is `local[*]`, which makes Zeppelin start a spark context just as done through the spark shell.
And just as the Spark shell can be pointed to an external master, you can use a value for the master URL, such as `spark://masterhost:7077`.
After this change (and possibly a restart), Zeppelin will only be running the driver, program, while all the workers and scheduling will be handled by your master.

Comment: can you explain that in more detail please, I don't understand what I have to do. I have a cloudera cluster running and want to use spark with zeppelin. "admin" is my HUE user. What I want is that the Spark application that is launched by Zeppelin has access to the files of this "admin" user on HDFS.

Comment: @Joha Added some additional info and a link to the documentation